# Django multi table inheritance represented with SQLAlchemy

Tags: django, inheritance, sqlalchemy

How can I convert django's multi table inheritance schema to an SQLAlchemy model?

It seems like the SQLAlchemy joined table inheritance method needs a discriminator column on the parent table. With Django's multi table inheritance, there is no such field.

```
class CommonParent(models.Model):
     field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ChildA(CommonParent):
    pass

class ChildB(CommonParent):
    pass
```

This results in 3 tables: `ChildA`, `ChildB`, and `CommonParent`. The child tables have an automatic foreign key added which is `(parent class name)_ptr`. Django uses this to pull the parent table columns.

With Django, a single `ChildA` instance results in a `JOIN` on the `CommonParent` table and all fields are merged into the class instance.

How can I replicate this behavior through an SQLAlchemy introspected model?

Any pointers in the right direction would help greatly.

Update:

In other words, I need the above django model relationship to be accessible through SQLAlchemy by calling

```
child_b = ChildB.query.first()
assert hasattr(child_b, 'field')  # field is from the parent table, `CommonParent`
```

In the same way I can do so with Django ORM:

```
child_b = ChildB.objects.latest()
assert hasattr(child_b, 'field')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways to present the data in `CommonParent` and `ChildA` in a single model: in Django, `ChildA` knows it has a parent in the table for `CommonParent`. SQLAlchemy uses a different approach, where `CommonParent` knows it has a child in the table for `ChildA`. On a database level you use Django's method, so that's what you want to mimic in your SQLAlchemy code.

More specifically, in Django, whenever you query for a `CommonParent`, you only get the data associated with the `CommonParent` class, and when you query for a `ChildA`, you get the data for both `ChildA` and `CommonParent` through a join clause.

The `CommonParent` class works good as it is in SQLAlchemy:

```
class CommonParent(Base):
  __tablename__ = '<tablename>'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  field = Column(String)
```

For the `ChildA` class you want to define a custom mapper that always performs a join statement:

```
metadata = MetaData()

parent_table = CommonParent.__table__
child_table = Table('<tablename>', metadata,
              Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column('commonparent_ptr', Integer, ForeignKey('<tablename>.id'))
             )

childa = join(parent_table, child_table)

class ChildA(Base):
  __table__ = childa

  id = column_property(parent_table.c.id, child_table.c.user_id)
  child_id = child_table.c.id
```

([Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables))

Comment: knbk, thank you! It was there in the docs all along.. Your help is much appreciated!